# mistake in ajax method post

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Please help me to figure out the mistake.. the problem is that if I put the name in the input with id="name" and press enter or button submit everything work, I have the alert success. PRoblem: as soon  I choose one of the options type=radio and click submit or enter I don't have message (alert-success)...

html part

```
  <form>
      <input id="name" type="text">
      <input value="1" type="radio" id="typeP">
      <input value="2" type="radio" id="typeR">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="button">
   </form>
```

javascript(jQuery)

```
$(function() {
    $(".button").click(function() {
       var name = $("input#name").val();
       if ( ($("input#typeP").prop("checked")) ) {
           var type = $("input#typeP").val();
       } else {
           var type = $("input#typeR").val();
       }
      var str = 'name' + name + '&type' + type;
      $.ajax ({
          type: "POST",
          url: "up.php",
          data: str,
          success: function () {
              alert('success');
          }
     });
});
```

Comment: `var str = 'name='+name+'&type='+type;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use the data like this

```
data: { name: name, type: type },
```

Also you are using the button of `submit` type, so when you click on that it will automatically submit the form. YOu should block that inorder to do the ajax. Use `event.preventDefault()` for preventing the form submission

```
$(".button").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDafault();
    var name = $("input#name").val();
    if (($("input#typeP").prop("checked")) == true) {
        var type = $("input#typeP").val();
    } else {
        var type = $("input#typeR").val();
    }
    var str = 'name' + name + '&type' + type;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "up.php",
        data: {
            name: name,
            type: type
        },
        success: function() {
            alert('success');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: OP's method isn't as easy...but is perfectly valid

Comment: @charlietfl can we put the data as query string in post method?

Comment: it is missing `=` though - `var str = 'name='+name+'&type='+type;`

Comment: @AnoopJoshi yes...but i did miss the `=` the form encoding gets done the same way for post

Comment: Thanks, I didn't change the ajax , but as soon I changed the ".button" it is works. Thanks.

Comment: Anoop...don't think of it as query string...it won't get appended to url. jQuery manages it internally to put it in request

Answer (score 2):

You need to prevent the default form submit. What you are likely encountering is the page is reloading

Change the `type="submit"` to `type="button"`

A button type does not trigger a form to submit.

Also as noted by others fix your missind `=` in the data string

Comment: thanks for you help but i use the first answer to prevent default on the submit button

Comment: no need to prevent default...if there is no default. That's the point of switching the type

Comment: yes I understand and your answer is one of the way for solution, than is useful, thanks

Answer (score 0):

The parameters as querystring should be passed as `'param=value'` you have missed the `=` to separate the param and value.

```
var str = 'name='+name+'&type='+type;
```

The `click` event wont work for `submit` button. You can replace it with `submit` handler`

```
$(".button").closest('form').submit(function() {

});
```

or prevent default action of the submit button using `event.preventDefault()`

The `if()` might be reduced to ,

```
if  ($("input#typeP").prop("checked"))
{
    var type = $("input#typeP").val();
}
else
{
    var type = $("input#typeR").val();
}
```

Comment: Yes it is my mistake when I copied it, but still thanks for you advises.